# Center dt elements in dl

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a description list like this:

```
<h2 class="page-title">Details</h2>

<div class="well details-form">
    <dl class="dl-horizontal text-center">
        <dt>
          Test 1:
        </dt>

        <dd>
            Test 1
        </dd>

        <dt class="margin-space">
            Test 2:
        </dt>

        <dd class="margin-space">
            Test 2
        </dd>

        <dt class="margin-space">
            Test 3:
        </dt>

        <dd class="margin-space">
            Test 3
        </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

The `text-center` class is a part of the bootstrap library and it only seems to center the `dd` elements, but not the `dt` elements.

Here is a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/a6uVpFdVWf) to give a visual of my issue.

How do I center the `dt` elements under the `h2` element (not directly under, but a little left so that the `h2` element is in between the `dt` and `dd` elements)?

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Picture from the answer provided by mhatch:

[image]

The result still looks like this: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/NEDEnNY3RS). Just centered `dt` elements.. but they aren't moving under the details `h2` element.

**What I am looking for**

```
                                          Details

                                    Test 1:     Test 1
                                    Test 2:     Test 2
                                    Test 3:     Test 3
```

Comment: Must be a problem with Bootstrap, on clean HTML works well: https://jsfiddle.net/4cpkusc5/

Comment: Works fine here as well: https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/49uLa9o2/

Comment: @stackingjasoncooper check link again

Comment: @Troyer my link is working now

Comment: @Syden check bootply link again

Comment: You should take away the `text-center`and override the default dt text-align.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid can you show us a pic of what you want it to look like?

Comment: @stackingjasoncooper updated

Comment: Do you really have to use a definition list `<dl>`? otherwise would be easier using cols

Comment: @TomSarduy honestly, this is the default layout for a details page.. so I figured I would try what they provided me.. but I do like your idea. I'll give it a go

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Did you see my answer? I incorporated a column to contain the list width, and used an column offset to center it.

Comment: @stackingjasoncooper can you provide code?

Comment: @stackingjasoncooper nvmd got it. I overlooked bootply link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to use the semantic of a definition list `<dl>`, I suggest you to change it to normal bootstrap columns. Otherwise would bee to much work to override default bootstrap properties to center the `<dd>` and `<dt>`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      Test 1:
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        Test 1
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tomsarduy/0z67j2pw/

Answer (score 1):

In the bootstrap styles the following CSS rule is setting the `<dt>` to align right:

```
.dl-horizontal dt {
    ...
    text-align: right;
    ...
}
```

Just add a CSS rule to overwrite it. **After** the bootstrap styles include this CSS rule:

```
.dl-horizontal dt{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This isn't moving the `dt` elements.. the bootstrap styles also set the `dt` elements to float left with a width of 160px.. I will update my question with a picture

Answer (score 0):

I recommend narrowing the `dl` column. Right now the `dl` is the full width of the well container, which is way too wide to get the desired layout.

You could use the Bootstrap grid system to limit it to a third of the container. See this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/1rPkvz056X).

Then you could go ahead and style the `dt` and `dd` elements more as desired.